# How to read Git notes using JGit given a commit-sha

Tags: java, git, jgit, git-notes

I am trying to read Git Notes information from a custom ref `refs/notes/abcd` of a particular commit in a repository using JGit

Here is what I tried:

```
Repository repository = repositoryManager.openRepository(repoName);
Git git = new Git(repository);
ObjectId oid = repository.resolve("5740b142a7b5f66768a2d904b267dccaef1a095f");
Note note = git.notesShow().setNotesRef("refs/notes/abcd").setObjectId(oid).call();
ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(note.getData());
byte[] data = loader.getBytes();
System.out.println(new String(data, "utf-8"));
```

I get the following compilation error:

> error: incompatible types: org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId cannot be converted to org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevObject

How do I pass a `RevObject` variable to Git `setObjectId()` given a commit-sha string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `RevWalk`, the object id can be parsed and the resulting `RevCommit` can be passed to the `ShowNoteCommand`.

For example:

```java
RevCommit commit;
try( RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repository ) ) {
  commit = revWalk.parseCommit( oid );
}

git.notesShow().setObjectId( commit )...
```

Comment: See also the ready-to-run example at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/AddAndListNoteOfCommit.java in my [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/)